# Zend framework - Zend_db_table_abtract select()

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I want to use `select()` where I can get just one column without specifying the table name. (Table name is in the $_name var declared in my model.) I tried this:

```
$select->columns('field');
```

.. but I get error of "No table has been specified for the FROM clause" - so it looks like it's expecting a table name.

Is there a way of getting just one column?

Comment: Where does `$select` come from?

Answer (score 2):

The error is correct. You need to specify a table you want the field from.

```
$select->from('table_name', array('field'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If your class extends the `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`, you can use `$this->fetchAll()` , so no table name need to be specified.

If you still want to use `select()` pass the `$this->_name` as you have already declared the value `$_name` .

```
$this->select()->from($this->_name);
```

`select()` is mainly used to create a select query object, so it cannot guess from which table you are going to though currently you are in the model. It may not be for a query on the same table. So you should pass the table name. For more see http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html . All are for different purposes. So you want to use according to your wish.

Comment: Using $this->_fetch() how do I specify a column name?

Comment: Sorry, I meant How do I specify a column name without a table name?

Comment: All the columns will be fetched.

Comment: Or in simple sentence `select()` is developed to work like that. Or you want to extend and make the necessary changes to work like what you want.